# Keycloak update role of user not reflect in flowable

Tags: keycloak, flowable

I am using the [Flowable](https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/tree/flowable-6.7.2) 6.7.2 version with Keycloak, I have created the realm from [doc](https://blog.flowable.org/2020/10/12/whats-new-with-the-flowable-ui-apps/). although Flowable 6.7.2 `docker-compose` file has its own realm JSON in Keyloak YAML file.

After creating all the steps from the doc, while testing I changed the role of the user, but it does not reflect on the flowable for the user. For role updates, **Flowable users need to re-login in the server**.

Is there any config changes to fix this glitch, or its work like this only.